# txn_id on paypal IPN is different than transaction number buyer gets on screen

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

How is it possible?
`txn_id` value seller gets (by [[image]paypal](/questions/tagged/paypal) [ipn](/questions/tagged/ipn)) is different than transaction number buyer gets on screen when he makes an order.

Are there two different id's for each transaction (client and shop)? or truely `txn_id` i am receiving is wrong?

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the buyer is paying with PayPal directly (i.e. Express Checkout) then the buyer will get one transaction ID and you will get another. It's confusing but it's how PayPal chose to do it.